# How to listen for data layer setStyle() over in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working on an application, that takes advantage of the Google Maps Data class. I have multiple data layers and when certain conditions are met I am switching the style of the data layers between visible: true or false. Everything work fine, but when there are too many features in the Data Layers this may take a couple of seconds and I wish to add a loader when this process has finished.
I am adding the styles like this:

```
             layer.setStyle((feature) => {
              if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === "Polygon") {
                return {
                  strokeColor: "blue",
                  strokeWeight: 1,
                  strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                  fillColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255)",
                  fillOpacity: 0.35,
                  visible: true,
                };
              } else {
                return {
                  visible: true,
                };
              }
            });
```

Also hiding the layers like this:

```
layer.setStyle({visible: false})
```

Adding the loader before the setStyle() methods and then removing after that doesn't work, because obviously setStyle() is asynchronous.

Comment: All events are [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data-Events).

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment, I am familiar with the existing events, but there is no such event that handles setStyle() end, please correct me if I am missing something. Is there any way to detect when setStyle() is done?

Comment: As I mentioned, **all** available events are documented. Your best option would be to file a feature request in the [API issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188853).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to wait for the setStyle() to over. I am posting this answer for everyone who are wondering how to do it.
First of all you need to know the total number of features in your DataLayer. It is possible to take it with layer.forEach() function, but it is better to keep track of the number of objects when you are setting them, so to skip this extra loop. Once you have the total number of objects in the layer, then you can use a Promise in order to track when the setStyle is over like this:

```
             let index = 0;
             this.mapLoader = true;
             const layerPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              dataLayer.setStyle((feature) => {
                index++;
                if (index === numOfObjects - 1) {
                  resolve();
                }
                if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === "Polygon") {
                  return {
                    strokeColor: "blue",
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.6,
                    fillColor: "rgba(0, 0, 255)",
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    visible: true,
                  };
                } else {
                  return {
                    visible: true,
                  };
                }
              });
            });
            layerPromise.then(() => {
              console.log("Promise is over");
              this.mapLoader = false;
            });
```

Although this method is far from perfect, because I am polluting the feature style, I can't think of other method for the moment.

I have filed a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249654823) as suggested.